# Which Python version should I use with Raspberry Pi running web applications?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm totally new in Python world.

I want to create a web application with some Python code behind. I want to use Python to control Raspberry Pi inputs and outputs etc.

There are Python 2 and Python 3 available. I've read some about these version, but I'm still not sure which version I should use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason to stick with Python 2 (e.g. a framework that has not been ported yet), you should *really* be using Python 3.

Quoting [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3), *"Python 2.x is legacy, Python 3.x is the present and future of the language"*.

Comment: Well... I haven't installed any Python yet, I have no idea if there are any reasons to use 2. There are many tutorials where Python 2 is used. I thought it's more "safe" to use older version (better community support etc.)

Comment: Note that writing Python 3 code and eventually backporting it to Python 2 is simpler than the opposite. So I suggest you start with Python 3 and if you realize that you need to set back, it won't be too difficult. Or just check if your favourite framework mentions any issue with Python 2/3. Speaking of web frameworks, Django, Flask, Tornado, Pylons all offer Python 3 support. Some third party plugins might not support Python 3, so check them too.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Do not forget, that RaspberryPi has limited resources. Python 3 is still about 10-17% less performant than Python 2.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky have a look to the RPi specs, I would not call that _limited_ at all! "10-17% less performant" in general is a bold claim, where did yoy get that? Also, web applications are almost always I/O bound, so raw performance is not really a big issue.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo You are right, 10-17% less performant is bold claim. About 3 month ago I made my own research on Python 2/3 performance, mostly related to processing text files and using information on web (not my own benchmarks). The number was my personal summary to what I have found, so I am not able to point to some simple page, claiming this number. Checking information today, I have found presentations claiming, Pyhton 3 is as performant as Python 2.7, but the performance really depends on type of task, which is done.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Regarding RPi being limited in resources: comparing to servers and notebooks, RPi is limited - memory, CPU, "disk" performance. If you read, that recompiling kernel for Raspbian takes about 14 hours, I would take it as sign of limited resources. Anyway, we will probably both agree, that RPi is great computing device with performance and resources, we would dream about some years ago.

Comment: Almost every week, any good reasons for preferring 2.7 over 3.x are reduced. Old ideas take a long time to be driven out of public perception: at v3.0 there were many valid reasons for rejecting the new shiny. I cannot think of an objection that still holds (although to be honest about it, when I'm doing something by myself, for myself, I tend to use 2.7 (old habits die hard)).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the books on the topic of Python and Raspberry Pi refer to Python 3.x. I'm finding a lot of online courses and books are focusing more on 3.x than 2.7.  Unless you're working at a company that's on Python 2.x and don't plan on going to 3.x, you're better off learning Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends, what web framework you are going to use.**

Some of them might have a bit limited functionality on Python 3 but still can be worth to use.

This could be case of `Flask`, which is very lightweight, provides all what you need, but according to heavy users lack in few small details complete support for Python 3. This situation is likely to be resolved in near future, but if you want to have it developed now, it is better to use the version of Python, which fits your web framework.

### Comments on few (not all) web frameworks

#### Django

Very popular, but will force you to do things in Django style.

Final solution can become a bit heavier, then really necessary, this could be a problem on Raspberry Pi, which has very limited resources available.

#### Flask

Also rather popular (even though not as much as Django).

Gives you freedom to use only what you need.

Very good tutorials.

Most of the applications run under Python 2 and Python 3, few (supporting) libraries are told to be not ported completely yet (I cannot serve exactly which ones).

#### CherryPy

Minimalistic web framework, but with very good builtin HTTP and WSGI server.

Not so easy to find good tutorials, best is using (now a bit old) book about programming in CherryPy.

Note: By default, the applications are developed in debug mode and code is autoreloaded from disk. This disk activity can slow down on RPi and consume some energy, so if you have troubles with that, set the app to production mode.

## Conclusions

My current choice is using Flask on Python 2.7, but this is partially due to a lot of legacy code I have developed in Python 2.7.

You shall make your decision about what framework you are going to use and check, what is status of Python 3 support.